# cuda 7.0 installation compatible hardware not found

Tags: windows, cuda, installation

I have a GeForce 8400 GS and compatible updated driver 341.44 installed on my Windows 8.1 x64 machine. When I tried to install CUDA 7.0 it showed that it could not find compatible hardware but I went along and chose to not install the provided driver and looking at this website [Nvidia Installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/) ran deviceQuery after installation but got this output.

$_ deviceQuery.exe

deviceQuery.exe Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL

$_

Help me install it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use CUDA 7 with a GeForce 8400 GS.  That is [a compute capability 1.1 device](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus) and [support for that was dropped in CUDA 7](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#unsupported-features).

Install [CUDA 6.5 instead](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive).  You can keep your 341.44 driver that you already have installed.

If you use CUDA 6.5, be sure to select an appropriate architecture e.g. `compute_11,sm_11` for your GPU when compiling codes.  CUDA 6.5 compiles for a cc2.0 GPU by default.

Comment: In fact, G80 support was dropped since 6.5 (See: [CUDA 6.5 Release Notes](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.pdf)). So he would probably need CUDA 6.0.

Comment: G80 (compute capability 1.0) support was dropped in CUDA 6.5, that is correct.  However GeForce 8400 GS is not a  compute capability 1.0 device.  Refer to the link in my answer for a cross reference to GeForce 8400 GS compute capability.  It is a cc1.1 device, which is supported (albeit deprecated) in CUDA 6.5.

Comment: It installed properly even `deviceQuery` and `bandwidthTest` returned results but the basic Visual Studio 2013 `kernel.cu` program fails and shows that the launch to `__global__` function failed. @RobertCrovella

Comment: Yes, because, as I said in my answer, you need to modify the architecture settings when you compile.